# How to load base64 image from file

Tags: html, image, base64

I am guessing this cant be done, but here goes. I need to load a base64 image in HTML, but I need to grab the base64 image data from a file, not encode it inline with the HTML. This needs to be straight HTML. It works fine if I encode the string in line as in:

```
<img id="base64Sig" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAA">
```

What I am hoping to do is something like this:

```
<img id="base64Sig" src="./Base64Image.TXT">
```

I have done a fair bit of googling and come up with nothing, but it cant hurt to ask. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up choosing a different path. I was trying to load a default image to a canvas element where the user signed their signature, then save that image to file. I decided to just start with a blank canvas as I don't think loading a base64 text file to an image tag from a file can be done.